# TypeError: on_press() missing 1 required positional argument: 'key'

Tags: python, keyboard

im pretty new to programming and i hope i can discribe my problem precisely.
i want to monitor the input my keyboard but i get this TypeError: on_press() missing 1 required positional argument: 'key'.

when i implement the function alone it works fine.

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
keys=[]
try: k = key.char # single-char keys
except: k = key.name # other keys
#if key == keyboard.Key.esc: return False # stop listener
if k in ['down', 'left', 'right',"up"]: # keys interested
    # self.keys.append(k) # store it in global-like variable
    #print('Key pressed: ' + k)
    keys.append(k)

return keys

lis = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
lis.start() # start to listen on a separate thread
lis.join() # no this if main thread is polling self.keys
```

... but if i call the function from the main

```
pressed_key = on_press()
```

the following error appears:

```
File "<ipython-input-7-c3f93c434982>", line 80, in main
pressed_key = on_press()

TypeError: on_press() missing 1 required positional argument: 'key'
```

Please let me know if you have any idea!

Comment: The error message tells you you're missing an argument. The `on_press()` function takes the key that was pressed, and you're not passing that.

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Answer (score 0):

As you defined in your on_press function. It requires an argument named key to work. When you call it from main without an argument it raises a type error exception telling you that the argument (key) is missing.

It works when you pass the function to the the on_press key argument in keyboard.Listener because the listener calls that function every time you press a key and it passes the key that you pressed to the function.